# Clicking on a page object in nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am writing e2e using nightwatch tests for a react web-app that has a table, with multiselectable elements.

To make the tests not break with every minor release, I want to use page objects to navigate the page. One of those page objects refers to the table. The table should have a function called 'selectRow(position)' and it should click on the row referred by the position.

This is my page object:

```
const listCommands = {
  selectRow: async function(position) {
    console.log(
      await this.api.elements({
        selector: '@row',
        index: position
      }),
    )
    return await this.api.click({
      selector: '@row',
      index: position
    })
  }
}

module.exports = {
  url: 'http://test',
  sections: {
    table: {
      commands: [listCommands],
      selector: '#Table',
      elements: {
        rows: {
          selector: 'tr[id^="TableRow"]',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

So the rows object contains multiple rows. In the selectRow function, the console.log actually prints the value of the correct element, however the click function throws me this error: `Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`.

What I want to achieve is that the correct row is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your command, you refer to the selector as `@row`, but in your page object, you refer to the element as `rows`. They need to match.

Also, make sure you are calling the `selectRow` method on the section of the page object, not the page object itself.